# Swift: Singleton returning multiple instances

Tags: swift, swift2

Below is the class I am using in hopes of creating only one instance of a singleton.

```
import Foundation
public class LoggedInUser {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var color: String?
    private init() {}
    static let sharedInstance = LoggedInUser()
}
```

The first time I access (setter) this singleton is inside a block, after making an async web call.  However, the next time when I access the same instance (getter), it appears that a new instance is initialized.  Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code doesnt seems anything wrong, did your property become nil on the next time you access this instance?

Comment: Pretty weird indeed...maybe should check if anything actually set your property back to nil (maybe nil user)? I don't think anything wrong with this, maybe the culprit is in some other place in your code

Comment: Either make LoggedInUser a struct or else make `sharedInstance` global (top level of a file).

Comment: Can you give a replicable example?

Comment: @matt - I changed it to a struct, the compiler is forcing me to change `sharedInstance` from `let` to `var`; however, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd like to see that replicable example too. So far this is all very theoretical.

Comment: I have the same problem. When accessing singleton from different places (seams from different threads) I have different instances. I thought "static let" should return same instance for all threads.